# Hibernate: Filter result list of entities by values of inner list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy.
Currently i have following entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Zone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "[NAME]")
    private String name;
}
```

And `Student` entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Student]")
@FilterDef(name = "zoneFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "zoneValue", type = "string")})
@Filter(name = "zoneFilter", condition = "zones.zone_id = :zoneValue")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_zone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "zone_id"))
    private List<Zone> zones;
}
```

So, i would like to get only that `Students` which have corresponding `zoneValue` in `zones` list. With current implementation Hibernate generates following query:

```
select student0_.id as id1_0_, student0_.age as age2_0_, student0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, student0_.tenant_id as tenant_i4_0_ from [student] student0_ where zones.zone_id = ?
```

So, it throws exception that `zones.zone_id` couldn't be bound.
 So, how could i filter Students by values of the zones? Is it possible to do that by using Hibernate Filter?

Probably, i have to put proper type in `FilterDef`, but when i write `Zone` Hibernate throws exception that it couldn't determine such type.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried to add</strike>

```
@FilterJoinTable(name="zoneFilter", condition=":zoneValue = zone_id")
private List<Zone> zones;
```

and remove

```
@Filter(name = "zoneFilter", condition = "zones.zone_id = :zoneValue")
```

(because I think the filter should be on the property and not the class)

then call

```
Filter filter = session.enableFilter("randomName");
filter.setParameter("zoneFilter", new String("myZoneValue"));
```

in order to active the filter?

---

I think Hibernate doesn't know the zones.value because you don't use an alias (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias)

This will give us something like that:

```
@Filter(
    name="zoneFilter",
    condition="{z}.zone_id = :zoneValue",
    aliases = {
        @SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "z", table= "student_zone"),
    }
)
```

Comment: it's not what i want to archive. With your code i will get filtered `zones` list, but i would like to filter `Student`

Comment: @iChrome I have updated my answer according to your needs :) Hope it will work!

Comment: unfortunately it also doesn't work:( It says that table `student_zone` couldn't be found

Comment: And if you replace "@SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "z", table= "student_zone")" by "@SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "z", table= "zone")". Maybe Hibernate want your table "zone" instead of "student_zone" (which is the join table). (the condition should also be replaced by  "condition="{z}.id = :zoneValue"")

Comment: Yes, i also tried `zone` table, but it anyway throws exception that it couldn't find `zone` table. It only doesn't throw exception for `Student` table, but i just don't understand why do i ever need to create alias for `Student` table in Student entity.

Comment: In your declaration of the zone entity, did you forget to add "@Table(name = "zone") ? In your example, I only see the annotation "@Data" "@Entity".

Comment: In the entity "zone", do you have the second side of the relationship zone -> student?

Comment: An other word, do you use the "find" method to fetch your students? If so, don't: the filter won't work with fetch, you have to request your student with an entity query. (Hibernate doc: "_Filters apply to entity queries, but not to direct fetching_")